# Flexible scp alias

Tags: bash, ssh, alias, scp

Suppose I have three files named myfile1.dat myfile2.dat myfile3.dat

```
scp myfile*.dat login@remote.com:./
```

would copy them in my remote directory.

Is there an alias to shorten this, possibly one that would also consider different input like folders, that is something like

```
myscp [scp options (like -r) only if given] [file name] [path in remote directory]
```

Using OS X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ssh config to store login information like this in file `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host r
  HostName remote.com
  User login
```

And then copy files:

```
scp myfile*.dat r:
```

I don't think there is a way to shorthen this command more.